# How to rotate rows between two background colors using itextsharp

Tags: colors, itext

Basically, for every odd row, show X color. for every even row, show Y color.

That is all the logic needed however I can't seem to find an elegant solution to do this with iTextsharp

My table name is  `PdfPTable logotable`

Answer (score 0):

Where you say "rotating", you mean "alternating". This is explained in the example [AlternatingBackground](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#221-alternatingbackground.java) in chapter 5 of the iText in Action book. The C# version of that example can be found here: [AlternatingBackground.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/raw/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/AlternatingBackground.cs)

You create a TableEvent implementation for which you define this method:

```
public void TableLayout(
  PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights,
  int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases
) {
  int columns;
  Rectangle rect;
  int footer = widths.Length - table.FooterRows;
  int header = table.HeaderRows - table.FooterRows + 1;
  for (int row = header; row < footer; row += 2) {
    columns = widths[row].Length - 1;
    rect = new Rectangle(
      widths[row][0], heights[row],
      widths[row][columns], heights[row + 1]
    );
    rect.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.YELLOW;
    rect.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    canvases[PdfPTable.BASECANVAS].Rectangle(rect);
  }
}
```

You use this event like this:

```
IPdfPTableEvent Pevent = new AlternatingBackground();
logotable.TableEvent = Pevent;
```

Try the standalone example first to see the effect. Then adapt the `AlternatingBackground` class to your own needs.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't see where Alternating Background() is located at?

Comment: "public class AlternatingBackground implements PdfTableEvent" is the class that teh above tableevent must be nested into. Is this java? I want c# equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying that the link http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/raw/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/AlternatingBackground.cs doesn't work? (Because it works for me.)

Comment: No Sir Bruno. I just realized that you wrote the code also and must therefore be some sort of itext/itextsharp nerd. My apologies. I did not mean to insult.